# Transactions between 2 fresh full nodes?

Tags: iri-node

There are 2 freshly setup nodes. They neighbor ONLY each other.

"numberOfSentTransactions" is increasing. What are these transactions? Who sent them?

Comment: We need more information to answer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see [in the code](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L555), about every 5 second, a node may run a tip request to it's neighbors, and this tip request increase the "numberOfSentTransactions"